# What's wrong with this MySQL execution script

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to execute a PrepardStatmenet in a Java app, however, I'm getting an error. Th evalues I'm passing are correct.

```
UPDATE characters SET level = ?, fame = ?, str = ?, dex = ?, luk = ?, `int` = ?, exp = ?, hp = ?, mp = ?, maxhp = ?, maxmp = ?, sp = ?, ap = ?, gm = ?, skincolor = ?, gender = ?, job = ?, hair = ?, face = ?, demonMarking = ?, map = ?, meso = ?, hpApUsed = ?, spawnpoint = ?, party = ?, buddyCapacity = ?, pets = ?, subcategory = ?, marriageId = ?, currentrep = ?, totalrep = ?, gachexp = ?, fatigue = ?, charm = ?, charisma = ?, craft = ?, insight = ?, sense = ?, will = ?, honourExp = ?, honourLevel = ?, damage = ?, showdamage = ?, totalwins = ?, totallosses = ?, pvpExp = ?, pvpPoints = ?, reborns = ?, apstorage = ?, name = ?, school = ? WHERE id = ?
```

For some reason, it gives me:

```
You have an error inyour SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = 1' at line 1
```

Ignore the "?". It's because I'm using a prepardstatement in a Java app.

This is the whole code:

```
 ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE characters SET level = ?, fame = ?, str = ?, dex = ?, luk = ?, `int` = ?, exp = ?, hp = ?, mp = ?, maxhp = ?, maxmp = ?, sp = ?, ap = ?, gm = ?, skincolor = ?, gender = ?, job = ?, hair = ?, face = ?, demonMarking = ?, map = ?, meso = ?, hpApUsed = ?, spawnpoint = ?, party = ?, buddyCapacity = ?, pets = ?, subcategory = ?, marriageId = ?, currentrep = ?, totalrep = ?, gachexp = ?, fatigue = ?, charm = ?, charisma = ?, craft = ?, insight = ?, sense = ?, will = ?, honourExp = ?, honourLevel = ?, damage = ?, showdamage = ?, totalwins = ?, totallosses = ?, pvpExp = ?, pvpPoints = ?, reborns = ?, apstorage = ?, name = ?, school = ? WHERE id = ?", 1);


  ps.setInt(1, this.level);
  ps.setInt(2, this.fame);
  ps.setInt(3, this.stats.getStr());
  ps.setInt(4, this.stats.getDex());
  ps.setInt(5, this.stats.getLuk());
  ps.setInt(6, this.stats.getInt());
  ps.setLong(7, ((this.level >= 250) || ((GameConstants.isKOC(this.job)) && (this.level >= 250))) && (!isIntern()) ? 0L : this.exp);
  ps.setInt(8, this.stats.getHp() < 1 ? 50 : this.stats.getHp());
  ps.setInt(9, this.stats.getMp());
  ps.setInt(10, this.stats.getMaxHp());
  ps.setInt(11, this.stats.getMaxMp());
  StringBuilder sps = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < this.remainingSp.length; i++) {
    sps.append(this.remainingSp[i]);
    sps.append(",");
  }
  String sp = sps.toString();
  ps.setString(12, sp.substring(0, sp.length() - 1));
  ps.setInt(13, this.remainingAp);
  ps.setByte(14, this.gmLevel);
  ps.setByte(15, this.skinColor);
  ps.setByte(16, this.gender);
  ps.setInt(17, this.job);
  ps.setInt(18, this.hair);
  ps.setInt(19, this.face);
  ps.setInt(20, this.demonMarking);
  if ((!fromcs) && (this.map != null)) {
    if ((this.map.getForcedReturnId() != 999999999) && (this.map.getForcedReturnMap() != null))
      ps.setInt(21, this.map.getForcedReturnId());
    else
      ps.setInt(21, this.stats.getHp() < 1 ? this.map.getReturnMapId() : this.map.getId());
  }
  else {
    ps.setInt(21, this.mapid);
  }
  ps.setLong(22, this.meso);
  ps.setShort(23, this.hpApUsed);
  if (this.map == null) {
    ps.setByte(24, (byte)0);
  } else {
    MaplePortal closest = this.map.findClosestSpawnpoint(getTruePosition());
    ps.setByte(24, (byte)(closest != null ? closest.getId() : 0));
  }
  ps.setInt(25, this.party == null ? -1 : this.party.getId());
  ps.setShort(26, (short)this.buddylist.getCapacity());
  StringBuilder petz = new StringBuilder();
  int petLength = 0;
  for (MaplePet pet : this.pets) {
    if (pet.getSummoned()) {
      pet.saveToDb();
      petz.append(pet.getInventoryPosition());
      petz.append(",");
      petLength++;
    }
  }
  while (petLength < 3) {
    petz.append("-1,");
    petLength++;
  }
  String petstring = petz.toString();
  ps.setString(27, petstring.substring(0, petstring.length() - 1));
  ps.setByte(28, this.subcategory);
  ps.setInt(29, this.marriageId);
  ps.setInt(30, this.currentrep);
  ps.setInt(31, this.totalrep);
  ps.setInt(32, this.gachexp);
  ps.setShort(33, this.fatigue);
  ps.setInt(34, ((MapleTrait)this.traits.get(MapleTrait.MapleTraitType.charm)).getTotalExp());
  ps.setInt(35, ((MapleTrait)this.traits.get(MapleTrait.MapleTraitType.charisma)).getTotalExp());
  ps.setInt(36, ((MapleTrait)this.traits.get(MapleTrait.MapleTraitType.craft)).getTotalExp());
  ps.setInt(37, ((MapleTrait)this.traits.get(MapleTrait.MapleTraitType.insight)).getTotalExp());
  ps.setInt(38, ((MapleTrait)this.traits.get(MapleTrait.MapleTraitType.sense)).getTotalExp());
  ps.setInt(39, ((MapleTrait)this.traits.get(MapleTrait.MapleTraitType.will)).getTotalExp());
  ps.setInt(40, getHonourExp());
  ps.setInt(41, getHonourLevel());
  ps.setLong(42, this.damage);
  ps.setInt(43, this.showdamage);
  ps.setInt(44, this.totalWins);
  ps.setInt(45, this.totalLosses);
  ps.setInt(46, this.pvpExp);
  ps.setInt(47, this.pvpPoints);
  ps.setInt(48, this.reborns);
  ps.setInt(49, this.apstorage);
  ps.setString(50, this.name);
  StringBuilder spss = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < this.school.length; i++) {
    spss.append(this.school[i]);
    spss.append(",");
  }
  String spss00 = spss.toString();
  ps.setString(51, spss00.substring(0, spss00.length() - 1));
  ps.setInt(52, this.id);
```

Comment: please edit the question instead of adding the datatypes as comments

Comment: @ArvindSridharan Main psot updated.

Comment: first run this query directly in db. Use Toad or some other tool.

Comment: is n't `int` = ? should be int = ?

Comment: there is no need to put `1` at the end of your `prepared statement`, `auto-generation keys` are only for `insert` statements

Comment: @SajanChandran Hmm what? I'm saving data into it, WHERE ID = 1.

Comment: @user2796592 you need to set the `value` for your `ID` in your `where` clause via your `Prepared statement`, in your command ` ps = con.prepareStatement("<update>", 1)`, there is no need for `1`.